# How to show product category description below list of products bottom of page?

Tags: product, magento2.2

I am trying to add category description on listing page on under pagination bar.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Open this file

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

> **Find this code:-**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml" before="-" />
```

> Replace above code with this code:-

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml" after="category.products" />
```

> After Clear cache and check

Comment: Please, stop suggesting the use of `$objectManager` in frontend, that is a `HUGE  NO-NO!!!!`

Comment: @VladPatru, I have changed the code, thank you

Comment: You should use the move like I posted above, you shouldnt have the block redeclared in your theme since it is already in the Magento default

Comment: This one working more convenient

Answer (score 3):

For a theme that has a parent `Magento_Blank` you can simply move the element within the layout file `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
<move element="category.description" destination="content" after="-" />
```

this will tell the block to move in the `content` container after all the other blocks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move the block in the layout

Add this code to `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
<move element="category.description" destination="content"  after="category.products" />
```

However, it should work for default *luma* theme. For custom theme it maybe will not work.

**EDIT**

Also, you can try to add to this layout next lines:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml" after="category.products" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this will help.